# Connecting a database to a phone

Tags: android, mysql, database, mobile

I am new to Android Apps. I want to create a database on my laptop but I want the information to be able to be accessed from it on my android app. I am looking for the best way to get the data from the database on the laptop to the app and update the database from the app. Any help/web pages with guidance would be much appreciated. I have done some research but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a database in your PC and program a web service in JSP,ASP.net etc .. and call the web service to fetch the table rows and return it to the app using any of the methods like REST/SOAP etc and parse it using any type of parsers like JSON,DOM or SAX depending upon what kind of data is your web service is returning with,
here is a tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: **androidhive is not a good tutorial source** ... to many bad code practices there ... this code will not work on devices with API >= 11

Comment: Bad code in the link aside - this is the correct approach. The question asks for a way to access a database stored on a laptop. The solution would be to use MAMP/XAMP/LAMP, connect to the laptop, and just load the information with a PHP script. This way you could sandbox the code on your local machine before deploying to an external server.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check ,this help you to create and populate your database at runtime,and preload database with your Android application.

> http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Hope this help...

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Android generally you deal with SQLite database, if you want to create that database from your system. you can use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) plugin for firefox. once you create database, you can move that database into Android device / emulator.then after you can use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which will help you to link with your database. I hope this will help you.